# C# Shorthand assistance

Tags: c#, asp.net, shorthand

Is it possible to shorthand the code below?

Essentially metaItem.Text is a string property that contains either "true" or "false" - I'm dealing with objects I have no control over here so I know it should be a boolean instead.

First, I need to check if metaItem.Text contains a value (i.e. not an empty string).  If so, convert it to a boolean.  Then set the Visible property of a user control (relatedLinks) to that value.

```
if (metaItem.Text != string.Empty)
{
    bool bShowRelatedLinks = false;
    bool.TryParse(metaItem.Text, out bShowRelatedLinks);

    if (bShowRelatedLinks)
    {
        relatedLinks.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        relatedLinks.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

The reasons for wanting to use shorthand is that I have a bunch of these conditions to show/hide various parts of the page.

Comment: metaItem.Text != string.Empty is fundamentally flawed. check also for stupid entries like a SPACE. All input should be sanitized, for 15 years or so I TRIM all input - people LOVE adding spaces at start or end without sense, mostly because they do not really see them.

Comment: metaItem.Text comes out of another system (CMS) so will only ever have "true" or "false".  It is literally a boolean converted to a string so won't have extra spaces or any thing other than "true" or "false"

Comment: As @TomTom pointed out in regards to `metaItem.Text != string.Empty` Try using `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(metaItem.Text.Trim())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool bShowRelatedLinks = false;
bool.TryParse(metaItem.Text, out bShowRelatedLinks);
relatedLinks.Visible = bShowRelatedLinks;
```

Explanation: Firstly, `TryParse()` can be given `null` (it will set out `out` parameter to `false` if parsing fails). Secondly, there's no need for the `if` test when setting `relatedLinks`. You already have the `bool` value, so just assign that.

If you're certain that `metaItem.Text` is `"true"`, `"false"`, or `null`, you can simplify further:

```
relatedLinks.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(metaItem.Text);
```

Comment: watch out for empty strings though, `Convert.ToBoolean()` will not like them

Comment: @paul: That's why I said if he's certain that it's true, false, or null.

Comment: yep, yours works for true, false, null, mine works for true, false, empty

Answer (score 0):

If your comment that

> metaItem.Text comes out of another system (CMS) so will only ever have
>   "true" or "false". It is literally a boolean converted to a string so
>   won't have extra spaces or any thing other than "true" or "false"

is really the case and you are able to be sure that the inputs will be the strings `"true"` or `"false"`, then you can simply write:

```
var showRelatedLinks = metaItem.Text == bool.TrueString.ToLower();
relatedLinks.Visible = showRelatedLinks
```

or

```
relatedLinks.Visible = metaItem.Text == bool.TrueString.ToLower();
```

if you want to make debugging more awkward ;)

Then there's no need to do any bool parsing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is about shorthand, here is one that is slightly shorter than Kent's:

```
bool bShowRelatedLinks;
relatedLinks.Visible = bool.TryParse(metaItem.Text, out bShowRelatedLinks) && bShowRelatedLinks;
```

It takes advantage of C# lazy evaluation.

And here is an even shorter version :)

```
bool b;
relatedLinks.Visible = bool.TryParse(metaItem.Text, out b) && b;
```

I included it because I try to keep local variables that are used on only one line named as simply as possible - it makes code easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

```
relatedLinks.Visible = (metaItem.Text ?? "").ToUpper() == "TRUE";
```

Comment: Fails if `metaItem.Text` is `null`, which he was checking for in his original code.

Comment: no he wasn't, he was checking for empty string, which is not the same as null

Comment: This code tests to see if relatedLinks.Visible is equal to (metaItem... etc.) , as opposed to assigning to relatedLinks.Visible...

Comment: sorry yes, changed `==` to `=`

Answer (score -3):

```
relatedLinks.Visible = bool.TryParse(metaItem.Text, out bShowRelatedLinks);
```

Comment: `TryParse` returns `true` if the conversion is successful, so your code will set the links to visible when `metaItem.Text` is `true` or `false`

Comment: The question was 'Shorthand' and not to code his logic. So I have given an idea and not fully functional logic.